# Google Colaboratory Export data to google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread, collaboration

I created the following code in google colab - I don't know how to get the data from the URL response (symbol, bidPrice, askPrice) to the export code to google shets - the export code works for me. I will be very grateful for your answer.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker?symbol=BNBUSDT"


payload={}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

{"symbol":"BNBUSDT","bidPrice":"272.30000000","bidQty":"410.84300000","askPrice":"272.40000000","askQty":"228.60000000"}


from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Open our new sheet and add some data.
worksheet = gc.open('16,09').sheet1

cell_list = worksheet.range('L1:N2')

import random
for cell in cell_list:
  cell.value = random.randint(1, 10)

worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
# Go to https://sheets.google.com to see your new spreadsheet.
```